# In Javascript, by what mechanism does setting an Image src property trigger an image load?

Tags: javascript, properties

One of the things you learn early on when manipulating a DOM using Javascript is the following pattern:

```
var img = new Image();   // Create new Image object
img.onload = function(){
  // execute drawImage statements here
}
img.src = 'myImage.png'; // Set source path
```

As far as I know, in general when you set an object property there are no side effects.  So what is the mechanism for triggering an image load?  Is it just magic?  Or can I use a similar mechanism to implement a class Foo that supports a parallel pattern?

```
var foo = new Foo();   // Create new object
foo.barchanged = function(){
  // execute something after side effect has completed
}
foo.bar = 'whatever'; // Assign something to 'bar' property
```

I'm vaguely aware of [Javascript getters and setters](http://robertnyman.com/2009/05/28/getters-and-setters-with-javascript-code-samples-and-demos/).  Is this how Image.src triggers a load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mechanism for `Image.src = ...` to trigger a load is currently unspecified, but [WebIDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/) will change that when complete.  ([4.4.5 Attributes](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/WebIDL/#es-attributes) is the section that talks about this right now; it's probably what will be in the final recommendation, but I try not to predict the future in these things -- too easy to predict in haste and regret in leisure.)  Some browsers have implemented this using essentially the getters and setters you note (just with "native" functions implemented in the browser to back them, akin to how, say, `document.appendChild` is a JS function with a "native" browser-provided implementation behind it).  Others have an entirely different approach for DOM getters and setters than for user-definable getters and setters.  (This is why, you can't use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` in Firefox 4 betas to examine DOM getters and setters.  It's something we will fix eventually, but we've run out of time to do it for Firefox 4, I think.)

For right now the answer is this: the "how" is unspecified, but it will be soon.

Comment: Just for completeness, could you mention which part of WebIDL pertains to this?

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to a JavaScript setter, but implemented in native code.  There are many others including [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) and [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent)

This [MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_Getters_and_Setters) explains the standard (ECMAScript 5) getter and setter syntax.  Unfortunately, [cross-browser support](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) isn't quite there yet.  Note that there's a vast array of prior [non-standard syntax](http://whereswalden.com/2010/04/16/more-spidermonkey-changes-ancient-esoteric-very-rarely-used-syntax-for-creating-getters-and-setters-is-being-removed/), most of which has been removed

Answer (score 1):

The W3C produces a specification that describes the behavior that browsers (user agents) should follow for HTML, JavaScript, and CSS.  Most browser vendors implement the JavaScript language so that it follows this specification.

The code you've described above, where the onload property is defined, is implemented in the native JavaScript packaged with the browser.  Each browser vendor implements something that quite possibly works a little differently under the hood, but the end result is usually the same.

You could very well follow this same pattern for your Foo object.  However, the only way I know to do this natively is by binding the onchange event to a DOM element.  The src property on the Image is the property of a DOM element.

Your Foo class would also need to bind the value to a DOM element if you were to take advantage of the onchange event.  However, there may be other ways of firing events when a property is changed (as opposed to calling a method that could set a property and also invoke other functionality.)